# Why aren't these functions printing?

Tags: python, list, function, python-3.x, printing

I'm having trouble with some code I wrote in the past. Is there a reason these functions aren't printing anything in terminal?

```
def count_evens_2d():
    count = 0
    xss = [[10,13,17],[3,6,1],[13,11,12]]   
    for i in xss:
        for j in i:
            if j%2 == 0:
                count += 1
    print(count)

def min_2d():
    xss = [[10,13,17],[3,6,1],[13,11,12]]
    lowest_val = None
    for i in xss:
        for j in i:
            if lowest_val is None or j < lowest_val:
                lowest_val = j
                print(lowest_val)
```

My logic seems to be correct in the first function I'm attempting to count all even numbers in that list of lists and in the second function I'm trying to find the minimum value in the list of lists. Thanks to anyone who can help

Comment: are you forgetting to call them, maybe?

Comment: @JimFasarakis-Hilliard yeah that seems to have been the problem

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should call them in your code as mentioned. E.g.:

```
def count_evens_2d():
    count = 0
    xss = [[10,13,17],[3,6,1],[13,11,12]]
    for i in xss:
        for j in i:
            if j%2 == 0:
                count += 1
    print(count)

def min_2d():
    xss = [[10,13,17],[3,6,1],[13,11,12]]
    lowest_val = None
    for i in xss:
        for j in i:
            if lowest_val is None or j < lowest_val:
                lowest_val = j
                print(lowest_val)


count_evens_2d()
min_2d()
```

I tried it and the printed values seem correct for the given list of lists.

Comment: Thank you so much I knew it had to be a simple fix